# Name for a certain type of metric/topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm learning general topology, and I know that equivalent metrics induce the same open sets, but I noticed that the family of open sets induced by the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is a subfamily of the open sets induced by the Euclidean topology. Is there a name for this kind of relation? (I couldn't find it online.)

Equivalently/more generally, if I view a topology $\varrho$ on a set $X$ as a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, is there any relationship between another topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $\tau\subseteq\varrho$? Will this ever show up in the future?

Comment: Look up the comparative terms weaker vs. stronger topology.  The main problem is trying to remember which one has the meaning you want. This certainly shows up in the future when you study more mathematics, like comparing the Euclidean and Zariski topology in complex $n$-space.

Comment: Weaker/stronger or finer/courser. They may also be incomparable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies

Comment: @KCd I remember it as “stronger”= “finer” = “more separation” (like the topology has to be really strong to yank all those points apart:)), then keep in mind open sets are how we separate things.